# How to fire `onAppear` method when a view comes back from `App Settings` changing a notifications setting?

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I'm trying to make an app using `Local Notification`.

I want to reflect on a set of `Allow Notifications` in an `App Settings` to some views.

But when a view comes back from the `App Settings` using a navigation link I attached(not back button), the `onAppear` method doesn't fire and I can't show a collect value...

**In my codes:**

- 1.Tap `Open Settings` to navigate to an `App Setting`
- 2.Change a Notifications setting
- 3.Tap `NotificationTest` button
- 4.Come back to `ContentView` then `onAppear` method doesn't fire

[image]

How could I solve this problem?

---

Here are the codes:

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isNotification = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(isNotification ? "STATUS:ON" : "STATUS:OFF")
                .padding()
            Text("Open Settings")
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
                }
        }
        .onAppear(){
            confirmNotification()
        }
    }
    
    func confirmNotification(){
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]){
                success, error in
                if success{
                    isNotification = true
                    print("Notification set")
                }else{
                    isNotification = false
                }
            }
    }
}
```

NotificationTestApp.swift

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct NotificationTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

iOS: 14.0

Life Cycle: SwiftUI App

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View has already appeared, just application is in background. Try to use instead (or additionally) `scenePhase`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @State var isNotification = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(isNotification ? "STATUS:ON" : "STATUS:OFF")
                .padding()
            Text("Open Settings")
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
                }
        }
        .onAppear(){
            confirmNotification()
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
            switch phase {
                case .active:
                    confirmNotification()
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For mixed UIKit/SwiftUI apps that still use AppDelegate, rather than SceneDelegate, you need to listen for `UIApplication` [lifecycle notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622953-didbecomeactivenotification). The scene phase approach doesn't work unless the `SceneDelegate` is implemented.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Text(isNotification ? "STATUS:ON" : "STATUS:OFF")
            .padding()
        Text("Open Settings")
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
            }
    }
    .onAppear(){
        confirmNotification()
    }
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { notification in
        confirmNotification()
    }
}
```